# How to download PDF in Opera with Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, opera

I'm using Selenium to create automated tests for a website in Opera browser. I'm trying to download a PDF file instead of opening it, but it doesn't work.
Here is my OperaDriver configuration:

```
OperaOptions operaOptions = new OperaOptions();
HashMap<String,Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
prefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadDirectory);
prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
prefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
operaOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
operaOptions.setBinary("c:\\Program Files\\Opera\\78.0.4093.112\\opera.exe");
WebDriver driver = new OperaDriver(operaOptions);
```

These preferences work fine with Chrome, but I assume it is different in Opera. Unfortunately I didn't find anything about it on the internet, could someone help please?

Comment: Can you show me your console log when it cannot be run

Comment: It runs, but the PDF file opens up in a new tab and it doesn't download. The download directory also remains the default.